# Distribution of $28$ objects into 4 heaps

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways can $28$ different things can be formed into $4$ heaps so that each may contain $7$ things?

Could someone give me slight hint for this particular question.

Comment: What distinguishes 4 un-ordered heaps of 7 un-ordered objects, from an ordering of 28 objects? First there is the order of the heaps, of which  there are $4!$ possibilities. Secondly there is the ordering of the heaps themselves, of which there are $(7!)^4$ possibilities.

Comment: Nice question..@MathGeek, what is your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the heaps are not labeled.

Object nr.  $28$ can be associated with $6$ other objects in ${27\choose 6}$ ways. The highest ranking left over object can be associated with $6$ other left over objects in ${20\choose6}$ ways, and finally the now highest ranking left over object can be associated with $6$ other left over objects in ${13\choose 6}$ ways. The last heap is what's left over now. The total number of ways therefore comes to
$$N={27\choose 6}\cdot{20\choose6}\cdot{13\choose 6}=19\,688\,264\,481\,600\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on whether the heaps are *labelled* or *unlabelled*.

**Labelled heaps:**

Imagine all permutations of the $28$ different things laid out in a line, with dividers after every $7$

Since we don't want to count permutations *within* a heap,

ans $=\dfrac{28!}{7!7!7!7!}= \dfrac{28!}{(7!)^4}$

**Unlabelled heaps:**

Now the order of the heaps, too, don't matter, thus $\dfrac{28!}{(7!)^4\cdot 4!}$

**Another way which some find easier:**

Distribute the objects turn by turn, viz.

$\dbinom{28}7\dbinom{21}7\dbinom{14}7\dbinom77$ for labelled heaps, (the last term given only for completeness),

and divide the above by $4!$ for unlabelled heaps.

Answer (score -1):

I would say, count of ways = $\binom{28}{7}\cdot\binom{21}{7}\cdot\binom{14}{7}\cdot\binom{7}{7}$

Comment: How? you should explain this.

Comment: Your answer assumes that the heaps are labeled, which is not clear from the question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: However, of the questions also does not follow that are not distinguishable.

Comment: I am not saying that your answer is incorrect.  My suggestion is that you indicate what question you are answering and how you arrived at your answer.